# What happens to a Wit.ai neural network if i delete an entity?

Tags: wit.ai

Suppose i have a bot of medium complexity. And i have this `client_location` entity.
[image: what happens if i delete an <code>wit.ai</code> entity?]

I want to delete it and create a similar entity that will contain only a portion of it's utterances.

Now from what i understand about neural nets, the meaning of something is saved in the network - so i can't see how it's possible to delete something and expect that will just work as it was not even there. Everything is interconnected -> so maybe it's not that simple to delete stuff.

I'm worried that this old entity i want to delete, will collide with the new one i want to create -> and will produce unexpected results.

Is this something to worry about? Can i expect to start fresh when creating a new entity?

**More general** - Is it safe to do `refactorings` in a bot? Or i need to create a new bot for each major `refactor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem changing something like that. If your change may modify the neural network (changing an intent for instance), it will just re-train.

It is not just training over the previous training. It will train from scratch again. So old version of your bot does not exist anymore.

It is not obvious to see it with wit.ai, but with a dialogflow for instance, you can see that each modification make your bot retrain, and the more intents you got, the longer it is to train.